# jQuery animation shifts margins for multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Here is what i currently have](http://jsfiddle.net/exLLop0s/1/)

I am looking to fade in the image without the text moving. Is there a way to do this? Do i need to modify the `.fade-in` element?

Comment: Do you mean the text moving as a whole or the line width changing (making the text look like it's moving)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your fiddle, I assume the problem is that the text is being pushed into a smaller region by the fade-in image, giving the impression the text is moving (the line width is what's changing).

To solve this, you need to give your text's class (`.row-text`) a definite `width`. That might cause it to still overflow as a complete `div` and move if there's not enough space. To fix that, since you already have `position: absolute`, just give it a specific `left` or `right` value to place it where you want it and it won't move. You might be able to skip `display: inline-block` in this case and just have `display: block` (i think that `position: absolute` causes both `block` and `inline-block` to be the same in this case, but not sure).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pews9d0d/6/)